# Can symAdd be used to overwrite a existing symbol in sysSymTbl?

Tags: c, vxworks

A function foo is already present in the system symbol table in vxworks. Now I want to know if I can replace symbol foo with similar function foo1 which takes same arguments and returns the same type as foo, using symAdd routine?

Comment: I dont see how you could. I don't think there is any way to "redirect" a symbol lookup to something else.

Comment: What about storing your own symbol _as_ foo, not foo1?

Comment: @mjs I can store my own symbol as foo, All i want is the calling functions of old foo should call my new foo implementation.

Comment: So try it. I am not sure if it will work - and it might depend when the modules calling foo are loaded. If you load your foo first, then the modules calling it, it might work. The other way round, probably not.

Comment: This seems a bit of an x-y problem though. What are you actually trying to acheive?

Comment: I cant load my "foo" module first. This is why i want to override the system symbol table.

Comment: @mjs I want to implement to a mechanism, where my ELF with a one version of foo is loaded. Now i want to change the foo implementation and make all the callers of foo to call my new version of foo without reloading/rebooting the ELF image.

Comment: I don't think you can do that, as the things that were already loaded will have picked up the symbol address as originally loaded. The symbol table is used at load time, not when the symbols are called.

Comment: In vxWorks when you load a library which has symbol "a" and another library which has symbol "a" as well. Both the symbols are loaded to different addresses. When the function "a" is actually called, then it depends on the OS which version of symbol "a" is invoked. So the behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be able to do this using system instruments. If some function `g()` invokes `foo()`, then this function is statically linked to `foo()`. This means, that `g()` body contains machine instruction like `call <hardcoded_address_of_foo()>`. This means, you can't replace `foo()` with `foo1()` without actually altering machine instructions either of all `foo()` callers or `foo()` itself.

However, altering machine instructions of some function on the fly is quite possible. So if you know your platform well, you can actually do function replacement trick on lower level. I successfully did this for VxWorks 5.5 compiled for MIPS architecture.

What worked for me (everything is done in shell):

- Get address of `foo()` and `foo1()` using `lkup`
- Calculate, how machine instruction `jump <address_of_foo1>` should be represented in hex
- Use `m()` to modify RAM occupied by `foo()` body in order to replace first instruction of `foo()` with calculated one, second instruction of `foo()` with `nop`. The latter is needed since all jumps are performed after executing one more instruction on my platform ([delay slot instruction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delay_slot))

As a result `foo()` is corrupted, but now it performs instant jump to `foo1()` while keeping all information intact (stack, registers etc), so it looks like `foo1()` is always called instead.

This is applicable to debugging purposes only, so you can continue debugging by patching code on the fly without writing new image to device. However, this approach shouldn't be ever used in production.

Comment: Thanks nnovich-OK, This helps me...Can you give any URL to study the use of m() that you mentioned to modify RAM occupied by foo()?

Comment: Take a look at [usrLib](http://www.vxdev.com/docs/vx55man/vxworks/ref/usrLib.html)

Comment: Also you might find l() from [dbgLib](http://www.vxdev.com/docs/vx55man/vxworks/ref/dbgLib.html) very handy for verifying written instructions. l(foo) will print disassembly listing of foo, so you can ensure, replaced instructions are fine.